# What's wrong with this simple SSL Vhost declaration?

Tags: apache, ssl, ubuntu-14.04, vhosts

Any reason why the middle vhost setting is causing an issue w/ Apache? Maybe it's because I don't have the SSL details in there?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.windfarmstudios.com
  ServerAlias windfarmstudios.com
  Redirect permanent / https://windfarmstudios.com
</VirtualHost>

#<VirtualHost *:443>
#  ServerName www.windfarmstudios.com
#  Redirect permanent / https://windfarmstudios.com
#</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName windfarmstudios.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/windfarmstudios.com/public_html

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/windfarm.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/windfarm.key
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/windfarm.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: 1) Why do you think its the middle one? 2) Is it supposed to be commented out? 3) What is the __"issue"__ it's causing? 4) You're better off asking on [ServerFault](http://www.serverfault.com)

Comment: Yeh, I can ask over at ServerFault. Apache won't restart when the middle Vhost is declared. I'm sure there's a way I can simplify this by bringing the redirect into the last vhost. Then there's only two declared. And all redirect to https://windfarmstudios.com

Comment: As you say, will be the conflicting `SSLEngine` probably. You're listening for SSL on all interfaces in the second 443 vhost so basically nothing else can bind to that address / no other vhosts can listen on it. Just put a `ServerAlias` for `www.wind...` in the ssl virtual host and use a host-header based `RewriteRule` for the redirect

Comment: Ok - so I think one of the important things to note here is that even when I get a successful redirect. You must have a wildcard or multi-domain ssl cert. As the ssl is checked BEFORE it tries the redirect. I have a multi-domain cert, but I'm not wasting one of my domains on a redirect. :)